# PDF downloadable PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

I need the file to be downloaded from the directory that is saved. I have used the following code

```
 $sqlh = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_health WHERE tbl_users_users_id = '".$id."'", $con) or die(mysql_error());

        while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sqlh)){

             $data['link'];
            echo "<a href='view.php?id=" .$data['health_id']. "'>Download</a>";

        }
```

view.php is

```
require_once('includes/db.php');
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_health WHERE     health_id='".$_GET['id']."'") or die(mysql_error());
echo $_GET['id'];
$data = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$file = $data['link'];
$name = "health/".$file;
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Length: ". filesize($name));
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=". $file);
$fp = @fopen($name, "r");
    fclose($fp);
}
```

The file is downloading, but when I open it the contents of the file are missing. When I try to open it through a browser it says **This PDF document might not be displayed correctly**.

Please can anyone tell me what I have gone wrong.

Comment: the echo will break the file

Comment: also i would change last 2 lines to:   `readfile($name);`

Comment: Thank You. I removed the echo and put your suggested readfile($name); and its working. Thanx :)

Comment: turned in to answer if you care to mark as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly the `echo` before the header calls should be giving you an error if you had error checking on.

then `fopen` creates a stream handle, but you do nothing with it. `readfile()` will send the file to the client.